# Исходный код в одну строчку

Tags: apache

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли настроить сервер Apache, чтобы он отдавал браузеру код в одну строку?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/). Он, к тому же, умеет минифицировать не только html, но и ассетсы(img, js, css)